# How to store content in a div on an external website into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-scraping

What I'm looking to do is to get content inside a div on another website (which I do not control) and display the content on my own website. For example, we will use these two sites:

- mysite.com
- othersite.com

On `othersite.com`, there is some text content inside a div that I want to fetch with javascript and update periodically (suppose, check every hour). For example, `<div class="some-div">9384</div>`.

Now, on `mysite.com`, I want to output this result into my own div using javascript. I suppose this would effectively be web scraping.

To do this, I would like to save a variable which updates occasionally like every hour.

Using jquery, I could define a variable and pull the content. If it was on the same site, which it is not, I could do this:

```
/* HTML with content to fetch */
<div class="some-div">9384</div>

/* get the content with jquery */
var getDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('some-div');
var getContent = getDiv.innerHTML;
```

If it was on the same site, then it would get the content inside the div and store it to the variable `getContent`. Here, `getContent` will equal `9384`.

Then I could use it anywhere I want, like replacing the content of a blank div on `mysite.com` with the content fetched from the `somediv`, like this:

```
/* HTML where the content will be output */
<div class="output-div"></div>   

/* replace the content with jquery form a stored variable */
var getMyDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('output-div');
getMyDiv.innerHTML = getContent.innerHTML;
```

The result would be:

```
<div class="output-div">9384</div>
```

But, the content for the `some-div` div is not on the same URL (and I don't control the other site).

How do I do the above, but instead of fetching `some-div` from the current page or site, to instead fetch `some-div` content from an external site (that I do not control)?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, look into the [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. However, whatever you're doing is likely to fail because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Your best bet is to create a server.

Comment: I have a server. But I don't own the website where I want to fetch the data from. Basically I want my page to crawl the page from another website and read the data and then let me store that data in a variable where I can use it as text.

Comment: To get past CORS, you need to send an AJAX request to the server, then the server sends the response to the target website, then the target website returns the response to the server which returns the response to the frontend. Then, you store it in a variable. What language is your server in?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the language of my server. Do you mean the language of the website or what the server is installed on? My website/page is in PHP and I can install anything on it including node, ruby, python, anything since I own the server. The server itself is running on Linux/Apache.

Comment: OP does mention he or she has zero control of the target server. "I don't own the website where I want to fetch the data from."

Comment: Your best bet (maybe) would be to "crawl" the target website with server-side scripting that you do control. I can't advise one server side setup over the other, but I do have experience in PHP and it could possibly serve your needs. Look into PHP's `file_get_contents()` and point it to the URL in question.

Comment: @GetSet PHP is also an acceptable solution. I just need a way to crawl the external site to fetch the content. Then I can easily output after I stored it into a variable, e.g. `<?php $theContent ?>`  (assuming of course that `$theContent` is a php variable in this case).

Comment: Well if you use `file_get_contents()` it will *only* return the html, without any client-side script rendering. So this solution may or may not solve your problem unless tested. I've heard elsewhere (here on SO) recently of using a programmable "headless browser" to get at the rendered front-end scripted based content.

Comment: That *is* html, because of the `<div>` tag.

Comment: @GetSet the OP doesn't have control over the target server, but they do have control over the server they own.

Comment: PHP will work for this. You can send the HTML to the client and easily [parse it with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/), then query the content from the div. Easy as pie.

Comment: Yeah @code OP just lost me made statement that the content is not html when it is clearly wrapped in div tags. But to say "PHP will work for this" is premature. It might not work for this, or it might: actual testing is needed in terms of whether the "div" is populated with content server-side when the page *initially* loads.

Comment: @getset sorry I meant something else. The content though I know for a fact is populated server-side because it's dynamic, the content itself must come from a database on the external site that I don't control. Basically I need a method to read the page as if a human navigated to it.

Comment: Well the key here is not when I said "server-side" but rather a distinction needs to be made: is the content rendered into the html or is it fetched via client-side scripts? If what you need to extract is rendered as is into the html then you can use the answers provided below, or even a PHP solution.

Comment: @GetSet ok, that's a good question. Only experimentation could be sure, because I don't have access to the code on target site. All I know if the content is dynamic and is pulled live in real time, so probably client-side would be my guess.

Comment: Ok if it's truly "dynamic" then look into "programmable headless browser".

Comment: That on headless browser I personally have never used. I plan to. However even if it seems like a formidable idea, or not suitable for your purposes, bear in mind that you can always program code to "upload" whatever parsed data from it to your actual needs. Not necessarily a feature of the "headless browser" but so long as it allows you to write data to an external file, the possibilities are unlimited.

Comment: Isn't there a simple way to just pull the content?

Comment: There might be. Run the tests to see if the content you need to extract is rendered in the html itself. That would be the simpler solution. However that solution will not work if client-side scripts pull in (or generate) the content. For the latter you will need something in play (a javascript runtime engine via a headless browser) to extract that "dynamic" content.

Comment: In the end I'm just deciding to use the api with the target server. The solution for this problem would have made it way easier to solve, and allowed situations where there is no api, which is the case in some instances that I want to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery:

```
$.get('http://othersite.com', function(data) {
    var $othersite = $(data);

    var getDiv = $othersite.find('.some-div');
    var getContent = getDiv.html();

    var getMyDiv = $('.output-div');
    getMyDiv.html(getContent);
});
```

If you want to use JavaScript without jQuery:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://othersite.com', true);
xhr.responseType = 'document';
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(e) {  
    var othersite = e.target.responseXML;

    var getDiv = othersite.getElementsByClassName('some-div');
    var getContent = getDiv.innerHTML;
 
    var getMyDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('output-div');
    getMyDiv.innerHTML = getContent;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about CORS, although I'm tempted to upvote for the fact that you wrote this on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

In other not to worry about CORS, you can try these steps:

1. Make an AJAX request to your server via jquery/javascript.
2. Make a request from your server to *othersite.com* via your serverside
   language (eg. PHP).
3. You can then manipulate the AJAX response any how you like.

**Example** - Step 1 and Step 3

```
$.get('mysite.com/some-php-file.php', function(data) {
    let $othersiteHtml = $('<div />').html(data);

    let getSomeText = $othersiteHtml.find('.some-div').text();
    $('.output-div').html(getSomeText);
});
```

Step 2 - You can put below code in a PHP file on your server.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "othersite.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: After extensive testing and attempts to even send my own browser's headers in the request, I still can't get the page to output via php. So, I don't think this is going to work. It works for google.com, but facebook.com/mypage doesn't output the correct page, neither does twitter.com/mypage, and I tried others as well, but to no avail. Even activated errors and no errors are thrown. Oddly enough, this page that we're on right now (on stack overflow) does work just fine. But not many sites that I tried.

Comment: After further testing, it seems what's blocking curl is cloudflare. Any sites using cloudflare won't work with curl. And the sites I need to use are using cloudflare.